# RSA private key decrypt function returning garbage values

Tags: python, rsa, private-key

I'am trying to decrypt the encrypted message with below code, basically reading the private key file inorder to decrypt.

---

```
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
import base64


def decrypt_message(encoded_encrypted_msg, privatekey):
        decoded_encrypted_msg = base64.b64decode(encoded_encrypted_msg)
        private_key_object = RSA.importKey(privatekey)
        decoded_decrypted_msg = private_key_object.decrypt(decoded_encrypted_msg)
        return decoded_decrypted_msg

def get_private_key(PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_PATH):
    with open(PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_PATH, 'rb') as file:
        pkf = file.read()
        return pkf

PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_PATH = "/file/path/xyz.pem"


privatekey = get_private_key(PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_PATH)

encrypted_msg = b'uVdNiaQoivUxRglJ9iAIsfqGlRVJV1IvZaDGIhZpDBlGgmsIzhWmAnIzXD1DQHUEGj5947mxHRTUhPgWlUit7CZDeP2KWD1SgvI6ZZda3OxwaK4y0Ao0cX1G+jgaY5x8hKNo5f03t565lYbq3dt9gj+haqNfy0d7fa8ZoFHlNfQwk/7RHJow1DtymuYyzELJ91nkY4eo6NHG2cQDXWPul/WEyWX1XhrlwGGrc+CClHUZqvVRiUSDQBo0YDnUD2DIkSm3ovGEI+DR/RVpFBEsG1DycsD0k63WqWMF12+Sdz2qIeX0WLQ5Mxfk017uzUpi+LlGPZLp4oYBr1vNmDZglg=='
decrypted_msg = decrypt_message(encrypted_msg, privatekey)

print "Decrypted message: %s" % (decrypted_msg)
```

---

Output:

```
ڋ�;�jU�e�a�d҃|�Ｚ�pN����qm��Lb"Z6�(�);�0�d��.*#�%ט�H<��XI��Lj����I#�P2��E����>�����x��ᚴ2��_�>��p%Rej�<B0U{�+;��b
```

However, i'am getting the decrpyted output with junk characters? How can i get the right string without junk characters?

Comment: What do you expect to see instead? Is the original plain text actual text or is it binary data of some sort, such as an image?

Comment: The only way for us to make any progress is to see the encryption code as well.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - I would expect to see the decrypted output in readable/plain text, original plain text is actual text.

Comment: @James K Polk, here is how the encryption is done
 
# Access key and password encryption using publickey

key = RSA.importKey(pub_key)
AccessKey_encrypt = key.encrypt(AccessKey.encode("utf-8"), 32)[0]
AccessKey_encode = base64.b64encode(AccessKey_encrypt)
Password_encrypt = key.encrypt(Password.encode("utf-8"), 32)[0]
Password_encode = base64.b64encode(Password_encrypt)

Comment: Please edit your question to put the code in it. There is an "edit" button just below the question you can use. Thanks.